# Bach und Ache, sind sie verwandt?

Tags: etymology, meaning, history

Sowohl bei der Ache (bspw. enthalten im Ortsnamen Eisen**ach**) als auch beim Bach handelt es sich um Wasserläufe.

Weiß jemand, ob der Bach auf das Wort Ache zurückzuführen ist oder eine anderweitige sprachgeschichtliche Verwandtschaft - also abseits der genannten Themenverwandtschaft - besteht?

Comment: Interestingly, the Grimm dictionary doesn't have an entry for *Ache*, while it does for [*Bach*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB00011#XGB00011) and [*Aue*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA05992#XGA05992), which - following [this entry](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ache) - is more closely related to Ache.

Comment: Habe ein bißchen recherchiert. Man meint, Bach ist nicht verwandt mit Ache, Aue und lateinisch aqua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly, the Grimm dictionary doesn't have any etymology on *Ache*, while it does for [*Bach*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB00011#XGB00011)

> *ahd.* pah *pl.* pechî
>   *altsächsisch* beki, biki
>   *der verwandtschaft zwischen* bach *und* πηγή [~pege] *wurde schon sp. 1051 gedacht*.

and [*Aue*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA05992#XGA05992)

> *ahd.* ouwa
>   [...] *deutlich aber hängt ouwa zusammen mit* **aha** *flusz*, *goth.* ahva, *lat.* aqua [...]

On [dwds.de](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ache), one finds

> Ach, Ache f. ‘fließendes Gewässer’, ahd. (8. Jh.) asächs. **aha**, mhd. ahe, s. Aue.

which would establish a somewhat direct link between *Aue* and *Ache*, a link, the sort of which is missing between *Bach* and *Ache*, since *aqua* [doesn't seem](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82ek%CA%B7eh%E2%82%82) to have ever had a labial consonant preceding it.

As far as I can judge this, both /ch/ seem to be products of the *Erste Lautverschiebung* (Grimm's Law), although this may be wrong for *aqua*.

Answer (score 3):

> **Aue, Au** f. ‘flaches, feuchtes, am Wasser gelegenes Wiesenland, (Fluß)niederung’, ahd. *ouwa* (10. Jh.), mhd. mnl. *ouwe*, mnd. *ouwe, ō, ōge* ‘Wasser(lauf), Insel (im Fluß), feuchtes Wiesenland’, aengl. *īeg, īg*, anord. *ey*, schwed. *ö* ‘Insel’ setzen germ. *awjō* (aus *agwjō*) ‘Aue, Insel’ voraus. Die substantivierte germ. Adjektivableitung bedeutet eigentl. ‘die zum Wasser Gehörige, vom Wasser umgebene’. Sie ist mit grammatischem Wechsel gebildet zu germ. *ahwō* ‘wasser, Gewässer’ in ahd. (8. Jh.), asächs. *aha*, mhd. *ahe*, mnd. *ā*, aengl. *ēa*, got. *aƕa*, das im appellativischen Wortschatz des Nhd. nur noch selten begegnet und im wesentlichen auf das Obd. beschränkt bleibt. Es ist als *Ache, Ach, Aach, Aa* in Flußnamen erhalten, öfter als *-ach* in Zusammensetzungen zahlreicher Flur-, Orts-, und Flußnamen wie *Aurach, Biberach, Lindach, Salzach, Urach* oder *-a* wie *Fulda, Schwarza.* Außergerm. verwandt ist lat. *aqua* ‘Wasser’, (…)
>
> **Bach** m. ‘kleiner Wasserlauf’, ahd. *bah* m. (9. Jh), mhd. *bach* m. f., asächs. *beki* m., mnd. *bēke* m. f., mnl. *bēke* f., aengl. *bece* lassen sich entgegen der bisherigen Meinung auf germ. *bakjaz* zurückführen, wenn man voraussetzt, daß lautgerecht entwickeltes westgerm. *baki* in die Flexion der *i*-Stämme übergewechselt, während anord. *bekkr* regulär aus dem mask. *ja*-Stamm germ. *bakjaz* entstanden ist; (…)

aus: Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen, dtv, 8. Auflage 2005

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe mal gelesen, daß **ALLE** alten Flußnamen bzw. Bachnamen "Fluß" bzw. "Bach" in einer älteren Sprache bedeuten. Leider konnte ich die Quelle dafür nicht mehr ermitteln. Es heißt ja auch, daß Ortsnamen die Friedhöfe der Sprache sind :-).

Comment: Hört sich plausibel an, aber "alle" scheint mir doch ein sehr kühnes Vokabel (auch ohne Groß- und Fettschreibung, zumal die Quelle nicht auffindbar ist).

Comment: Auf jeden Fall nochmal die Antwort bearbeiten, falls die Quelle aufgefunden wird. Klingt interessant.

Comment: Hmm, muß ich mich wohl doch nochmal bemühen :-). Ich hatte mal ein Buch von einem der Berlitz-Enkel mit Sprachvergleichen bezüglich Sprichwörtern. Vielleicht war es das ja ...

Answer (score -1):

Die Idee ist nicht von der Hand zu weisen. Mit einem Präfix *b-* ist prinzipiel von einer B-deutung *bei* auszugehen. Eine befriedigende Lösung ist jedoch nicht zu erwarten, da für *-ach* (*Eisenach*, *Achen*) bzw. *-au* und daneben *Gau* mit ga-Präfix nur recht wenig auf eine urindogermanische Wurzel hindeutet, die dennoch als allgemein akzeptiert gilt.

Da ist zum einen lateinisch *aqua* "Wasser". Daneben bestehen nur hypothetische Vergleiche. Ein Entlehnung in den vorgermanischen Wortschatz aus unbestimmter Quelle ist immerhin denkbar.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aqua

Für *Bach* sei zuerst auf Pfeifer verwiesen, ferner Lloyd.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Bach

https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/bah1/de

Demnach besteht Einigkeit in den westgermanischen Begriffen *beki* usw. proto-west-germanisch **baki* bzw. urgermanisch **bakjaz* unter Einbezug skandinavischer Sprachen, jedoch ohne Gotisch, das zumindest *ahwa* “Fluss” bezeugt. Mit niederländisch *beek* lässt sich noch eine weitere, jüngere und leicht verfügbare Referenz heranziehen, s. Philippa *et al.*:

> algemeen geaccepteerd is alleen verwantschap met Iers *búal* ‘water’ (misschien < pie. **bhog-lā*); onzeker is de relatie met Litouws *bėgti*; Oudkerkslavisch *běžati* ‘lopen’. Mede gezien het betekenisveld is dit wrsch. een West-Europees substraatwoord.

https://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/beek1

So ähnlich auch Wiktionary, die von der Unsicherheit jedoch wie so oft nichts sagen.

Darüber hinaus herrscht Ungewissheit hinsichtlich möglicher Vergleiche. Deswegen, auch hinsichtlich Substrat, sofern man an innergermanische Entlehnung denken möchte, ist die Frage im Grunde nicht zu verneinen. Da *aqua* vel sim. aber auch als unsicher gelten dürfte, ist die Möglichkeit anderweitiger Vergleiche nicht auszuschließen. Bezugnahme auf Wortgefüge samt Präfixen macht die Sache nicht einfacher.

Im Schluss bleibt zu bemerken, dass die Gaum-en-laute in urindoeuropäischer Rekonstruktion als **h₂ékʷeh₂* bzw. **bʰog-* nicht ohne weiteres Vereinbar wären, was insofern unbeachtlich bleibt, wenn man einzelsprachliche Entlehnungsvorgänge rekonstruieren möchte.

---

In eigener Sache sei zu guter letzt insbesondere auf *Teich* und *Deich* verwiesen, sowie vergleichbar niederländisch *waal*, das zuerst westflämisch begegnet und etwa “kolk na dijkdoorbraak” bedeutet (Philippa *et al.*) — etwa *Teich nach Deichbruch*. Siehe übrigens *der Kauler* in *Kaulsdorf* (Berlin). Siehe außerdem *vacal, vahal* “die Waal” als Hydronym schon in römischen Quellen.

Dieses Thema, der Deichbruch, hat mich überhaupt erst zu der Frage geführt (Lösungsvorschlag in verwandten Fragen bei der Fragestellung). In dieser Hinsicht ist beachtlich, dass noch eine andere Sippe unter **bʰeg-* "to break" geführt wird, siehe Wiktionary.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Teich

https://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/waal1

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/b%CA%B0eg-

PS: dazu zählt das Wiktionary auch engl. *bicker*. Vgl. idiom. *reden wie ein Wasserfall*. Siehe außerdem idiom. *nahe am Wasser gebaut* (“prone to cry"), bzgl. *bau-*.